# How to pass kerberos authentication through IIS to Flask Oracle connection?

Tags: python, oracle, flask, iis, kerberos

On a Windows server, I have a simple Flask app to connect to an Oracle database using kerberos authentication.  If I run from command line with Python.exe App.Py, the app successfully connects to Oracle DB using cx_Oracle and runs a simple query and returns the JSON results to the web page.

Next I setup IIS to run Flask apps and I was able to get a simple Hello World Flask app to return a page.

Now I need to run the same Flask app through IIS to connect to the Oracle Database using Kerberos, but the connection fails.  Although my ID can establish the connection through Flask command line app or SQLPlus connection, it behaves as if my credentials are not passed through IIS to the Flask app.  IIS is setup to use Windows Authentication.

Is there a way to pass through my credentials in IIS so that it establishes the Oracle connection in Flask just like it does when running from the command line?

Comment: I am new to Kerberos, but I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @DavidBullock I can run the flask app.py from command line with 
`python.exe api.py` and connection to oracle from flask works just fine. But, for security reasons, I need IIS to call the app.  When IIS calls the app, it throws a 500 error.

I know a basic hello world Flask app works in IIS.  I know that Flask app can successfully connect to Oracle DB if run from command line.  What doesn't make sense is why trying to run the app via IIS crashes python when trying to connect to the database.

Comment: Can you post detailes of 500 error? For example, its sub-status code, error message and error code.

Comment: @samwu how do I do that?

Comment: You can post a screenshot of your error page.

Comment: Don't have a screenshot to send.  It looks like something in IIS is preventing the Kerberos credentials from being passed to the Flask app and then to cx_Oracle connection.  From command line, Flask app runs fine without IIS frontend, but trying to run through IIS it fails.  If you have any links to examples of how I might do this, please let me know.